# How feasible is to use other delegates in app delegate file in iOS 4.2?

Tags: delegates, ios4, uiapplicationdelegate

How feasible is it to use other delegates in app delegate file .
e.g.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>{
BOOL LoadingForFirstTime;
}
```

Is this recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, **Yes** it is feasible, **No** it is not recommended.

Typically the AppDelegate should handle system notifications, core data setup and not a whole lot more.  Check out Table 2.1 here:
[Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html)

I am guessing, from the BOOL you are defining, that  you are checking if this is the first load.  This might work, but it isn't recommended practice.

Comment: Thank you.. I just wanted to know if my app will get rejected if I do this

Comment: Beyond 'private API' use, there are few hard and fast rules about rejection.  That said, I doubt Apple cares that much if your code is 'clean' or not.  They may have an issue with how & when you display warnings though if they result in a negative user experience / flow through the app.